# Download of a file geodatabase failing when using script and query

Tags: arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to download a file geodatabase using a script. The script is taken from the Esri documentation with minimal changes, basically I'm querying for the required feature layer appending date and time and exporting as a FGDB. The script works as expected by creating the FGDB on AGOL, but when I try and download the FGDB the script fails and fails to export to my local file plan, I can't figure out what is stopping the download, my code is a follows

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import datetime as dt
username = "CSV_GIS_Defects"
gis = GIS('url','username','password', verify_cert=False, proxy_host='proxy', proxy_port=port)
folder_path=r'D:\ArcGisExportData\GeoDatabase'
items = gis.content.search(query="title:CSV_GIS_Defects", item_type="Feature Layer", sort_field='modifed', sort_order='desc')
print(str(len(items)) + " items will be backed up to " + folder_path +". See the list below:")
items

def download_as_fgdb(item_list, backup_location):
    for item in item_list:

        try:
            if 'View Service' in item.typeKeywords:
            print(item.title + " is view, not downloading")
       else:
            print("Downloading " + item.title)
            version = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%b_%Y")
            print(version)
            result = item.export(item.title, "File Geodatabase")
            print(result)
            result.download(backup_location)
            result.delete()
            print("Successfully downloaded " + item.title)
    except:
        print("An error occurred downloading " + item.title)
        print("The function has completed")

download_as_fgdb(items, folder_path)
```

The errors I receive in Jupyter

> 1 items will be backed up to D:\ArcGisExportData\GeoDatabase. See the
> list below: Downloading CSV_GIS_Defects 03_Mar_2022 <Item
> title:"CSV_GIS_Defects" type:File Geodatabase owner:shaw_b> An error
> occurred downloading CSV_GIS_Defects The function has completed

I removed the try/except block and the error was exposed.  The error is coming back as an Https proxy timeout, I supply the proxy settings in my connection parameters, they work fine for other scripts my error is

> 'Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'

Comment: Accord to the API help it says this about the export method - _However, it is available only to users with an organizational subscription and can only be invoked by the service item owner or an administrator, unless a Location Tracking Service or Location Tracking View is used._

Comment: I had read this our organization has a subscription for 40 users, my profile is set up as admin. I have created similar scripts that export and download csv files, for some reason when trying to download as a file geodatabase seems to be creating an issue